# creating ubuntu machine as a hotspot

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop. I want to make my laptop as hotspot for my android phone to access internet.
Is it possible if yes What step need to follow.
I already have tried creating the " use as hotspot" by any android phone is unable to view this AP for as wifi.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to know that Android does not "see" ad-hoc networks. You have to create a hotspot.

Second, you have to make sure you wlan card is hotspot-capable. This is called [master mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode). If it is, then you can use [hostapd](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd), quitesimple to start and configure given a config file. As example I use this:

```
$ cat ~/hostapd-minimal.conf
#change wlan0 to your wireless device
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=test
channel=1
hw_mode=g
$ sudo hostapd ~/hostapd-minimal.conf
```

My machine runs on Linux Mint 12, which is based on Ubuntu-11.10. And I faced some issues because of IPv6. I got this error in syslog:

```
$ dmesg
[  453.348841] rtl8192c: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[  464.654466] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

This error is very common and is painful to work around with *poor* network manager... It has been reported on Ubuntu several times:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/857294
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/830178

To fix it, you have to try proposed solutions, I haven't yet.

Comment: Actually, if you don't like the idea of writing a configuration file for `hostapd`, the popular NetworkManager tool also supports managing an AP now, but this is not available through its GUI tools; it requires a manual tweak in its configuration file for `mode=ap`. Reference in Russian: http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.B0_.D0.B2_NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

take a look here and you'll be able to create the hotspot easily: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/